# Cypress commandline for rerun the failed TC

Tags: cypress

For re running the failed test case i saw the below option to put in cypress config file

```
{
  "retries": {
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress run`
    // Default is 0
    "runMode": 2,
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress open`
    // Default is 0
    "openMode": 0
  }
}
```

But i need to pass this value via command line while starting the automation , how i can pass the above value from command line

Comment: Use environment variables instead of hard-coding values?

Comment: "I need to pass this value via command line while starting the automation" -> Can you explain why you have to do that? Why will setting these in the config file not work in your case?